# Algorithm to compute the difference between two geometric paths

Tags: computational-geometry

I want to compute the difference/intersection between two paths. By path I mean a list of points that can be created by the following actions on a graphics context:

- move to x, y
- line to x, y
- Bézier to x, y

How could I do that? What's the best algorithm to compute the difference/intersection between two paths, A - B? What if there's a simplification where B is guaranteed to be a rectangle?

Comment: I don't think this is answerable.  There are many possible ways one could define a distance between two paths.  Without any way to select among from them, there's no way to answer.  "best" is not a useful criterion because you haven't told us by what standard you plan to evaluate possible distance measures.  I don't think this is an answerable question -- first, you need to figure out how you plan to measure distance, and what properties you want it to have.